# how to make flash object fullscreen in HTML?

Tags: html, flash, fullscreen

how can I make a flashobject to display in fullscreen in HTML? (without having the flash source)

Comment: read on flash to HTML5 conversion

Comment: that might work for simple animations, but I highly doubt that this works for Applications

Comment: try this http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/full_screen_mode.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do this from outside of Flash.  Fullscreen mode is triggered by setting the fullScreen property of stage:

```
stage.displayState = "fullScreen";
```

Without being able to do this you can't use the fullscreen player.  One option for you might be to create a wrapper SWF that loads in your existing content, opens into fullscreen mode, then scales your existing content to the full screen size by reading `flash.system.Capabilities::screenResolutionX`. Something like this:

```
//assume content SWF is already loaded and on the stage
function resize():void
{
    stage.displayState = "fullScreen";
    loadedSWF.x = 0;
    loadedSWF.y = 0;
    loadedSWF.width = flash.system.Capabilities.screenResolutionX;
    loadedSWF.width = flash.system.Capabilities.screenResolutionY;
}
```

How well this works will depend on the existing scaleMode setting of the SWF that you will be loading in.

Comment: +1 Wrapper SWF would work well. Can you change the scaleMode of the loaded SWF via `Loader`'s `content` property? ie `Loader.content.stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE?`

Comment: Good question, I don't honestly know if it would work. Certainly worth trying.

Answer (score 1):

Make the width and height of the embedded code 100%.

Comment: but this is not fullscreen, the browser is still visible then