# full screen button create

Tags: html, wordpress, flash, online-game

i use iframe plugin to embed swf file for playing game in my website. but i want to show below of this game a full screen button. how i can do it?i use WordPress. my site http://www.dewdropzone.com some thme i use this type of embed code.

```
<div align='center'>
<object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=9,0,16,0" id="game" height="490" width="650">
<param name="movie" value="http://www.cricketgames.me/games/swf/cricket-rivals.swf" />
<param name="quality" value="high" />
<param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always" />
<embed src="http://www.cricketgames.me/games/swf/cricket-rivals.swf" height="490" width="650" quality="high" name="FlashContent" allowscriptaccess="always" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer"></embed>
</object>
<br /><a href='http://www.cricketgames.me/'>Cricket Games</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8185969/fullscreen-webpage-presentation or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8159351/how-to-make-flash-object-fullscreen-in-html

Comment: not like this. i want creat a full screen toggle button for your swf file in wordpress. anyone can tell me. and give me details where i input this code.

Comment: srry :) .i want creat a full screen toggle button for my swf file in wordpress in my site. anyone can tell me. and give me details where i input this code.